# Does carboxyl group interfere with reaction of 2-carboxybenzaldehyde with NaCN/HCl?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, carboxylic-acids

The aldehyde group of [2-carboxybenzaldehyde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Carboxybenzaldehyde) reacts with $\ce{NaCN/HCl}$ forming [cyanohydrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanohydrin). Does the carboxyl group remain intact? Does it react separately or with the cyanohydrin?

I suspect possible intervention of the lone pair from the $\ce{-CN}$ group to form an aromatic ring. Does it (or something else) happen or not?

Comment: formation of the 3-cyanophthalide looks like a possibility.

Comment: @Waylander: If it happens, it should proceed by protonation of the $\ce{-OH}$ and then attack of the carboxylic acid, removing $\ce{H_2O}$ right? (That's what I was thinking in the first place)

Comment: That seems a reasonable mechanism. I do not have database access to try to find an example, maybe someone else who has can give a definitive answer.

Comment: @Waylander: The reaction is known to give what you predict but with a twist. The crude, presumable cyanohydrin, is isolated. The residue is treated with DCC to effect lactonization. Chem. Absts. is unaware of the cyanohydrin. [Y. Li, A. Linden, M. Hesse, *Helv. Chim. Acta*, **2003**, *86*, 579.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Waylander's suggestion that 3-cyanophthalide [3-oxo-1,3-dihydroisobenzofuran-1-carbonitrile] **6** is expected as the product of the reaction is well-reasoned. This reaction has been reported by Hesse, et al.<sup>[[1]](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/hlca.200390058)</sup> The reaction of aldehyde **1** in the presence of sufficient aq. HCl to generate HCN and enough to act as a catalyst for the reaction does not provide **6** directly. The cyanophthalide **6** is not formed under the conditions employed but, seemingly, the cyanohydrin **2**, which was isolated by extraction with ethyl acetate. The crude material was lactonized with dicyclohexylcarbodiimide [DCC] **3** as shown in the steps **2** $\rightarrow$ **6**.

[image]

1. Y. Li, A. Linden, M. Hesse, [*Helv. Chim. Acta*, **2003**, *86*, 579](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/hlca.200390058).

Comment: I understand this, but in absence of **3**, would it not be possible for the hydroxy group in cyanohydrin to get protonated, followed by intramolecular attack of the carboxylic acid?

Comment: Perhaps under some set of conditions but not likely in my opinion. The facts are what they are!